# Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm unable to use any new modules in my flask app. I can confirm that the stripe module that is causing an error is installed. As I can import it fine using the python shell.

The error I am getting:

```
    [Mon May 18 14:57:57.214930 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7363:tid 140133659481856] [client 86.171.45.198:58453] mod_wsgi (pid=7363): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
    [Mon May 18 14:57:57.214997 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7363:tid 140133659481856] [client 86.171.45.198:58453] mod_wsgi (pid=7363): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
    [Mon May 18 14:57:57.215572 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7363:tid 140133659481856] [client 86.171.45.198:58453] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Mon May 18 14:57:57.215606 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7363:tid 140133659481856] [client 86.171.45.198:58453]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
    [Mon May 18 14:57:57.215614 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7363:tid 140133659481856] [client 86.171.45.198:58453]     from flaskapp import app as application
    [Mon May 18 14:57:57.215621 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7363:tid 140133659481856] [client 86.171.45.198:58453]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.py", line 5, in <module>
    [Mon May 18 14:57:57.215627 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7363:tid 140133659481856] [client 86.171.45.198:58453]     from CENSORED import classes (CENSORED) 
    [Mon May 18 14:57:57.215634 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7363:tid 140133659481856] [client 86.171.45.198:58453]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/mannion.py", line 15, in <module>
    [Mon May 18 14:57:57.215639 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 7363:tid 140133659481856] [client 86.171.45.198:58453]     import stripe
    [Mon May 18 14:38:26.822729 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 6511:tid 140222923097856] [client 46.4.105.116:31880] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stripe'
```

contents of flaskapp.wsgi

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/flaskapp')
from flaskapp import app as application
```

contents of /etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi

        <Directory flaskapp>
                WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this? If you need any more information I'll be happy to provide.

EDIT:

sys.path output from flaskapp.wsgi location:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Python Shell version:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 

>>> import stripe; print(stripe.__file__)
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/stripe/__init__.py
```

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the entire error message?  The last line is `import stripe`, and that is not in itself an error.

Comment: The flask webserver is probably using a different version of python, and you don't have `stripe` installed for that version.  In flaskapp.wsgi, print `sys.path` and show us that output, and also show us the python version from the shell.

Comment: In the python shell, show us the output of `import stripe; print(stripe.__file__)`

Comment: Added to the python shell version block. You'll see why I'm so confused haha